# We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.1

I am getting the below warning message when post or save the data using webforms in sitecore

> We experienced a technical difficulty while processing your request. Your data may not have been correctly saved.

Although, data saves into the database i am getting this warning.

```
Sitecore App version : 7.1
Webforms for marketers version : 2.3.0
```

Need your help in resolving this.

Comment: If your webform contains, Send Email message action, configuring the smtp host on submit action should resolve this.

Comment: You should probably shape your comment into an answer and accept it eventually

Answer (score 4):

It may not be obvious for others reading this where to change the SMTP host settings for the `Send Email Message` save action. There is an XML snippet in the `Parameters` field of the action item:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Settings/Actions/Save Actions/Send Email Message`

Comment: The Action is called "Send Mail" in previous versions.